# Converting an address to geolocation and adding a range

Tags: ios, latitude-longitude

I have  city address and state on my server.

I need to fetch data in my iPhone application as per distance range (i.e in miles).

Please give some proper suggestions.

Comment: Please ask proper Questions !

Comment: it only means that i dont have latitude and longitude available in my db.

Comment: Did you mean you need lat-long from city address and state ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingRequests) to get Lat-Long form address.

For example :

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=newyork,us
```

> address — The address that you want to geocode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [google geolocation service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), where it will get the Lat long from the address or vice-a-versa.

Please read the [FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq) for the same.

Another is [Foursquare](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) which also nice to use and provides good data.

This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can travel to each of your cities and measure the highest position of some stars.
Through the [altitude relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culmination) you can calculate then you current latitude.

The longitude is a bit more complicated. You need an accurate clock and a table/chart of star positions/times. Then you take measure the time of the highest position of some stars and compare it to your table. with the difference of this two values you can calculate the longitude of the city.

But there are already people who did that and share their results.

Comment: This was a golden responde :D